# How open a webview from RSS feeds

Tags: java, android, eclipse, rss

I have a simple RSS reader which displays items from a given feed, the problem I am having is that I do not know how to get the url for the news item so that when the user clicks on the item it opens in a webview, I know how to pass a string to another class open a webview ect... but I do not know how to get the url so I can open the item. Below is the article class;

```
    public static List<JSONObject> getLatestRssFeed(){
    String feed = "http://globoesporte.globo.com/dynamo/futebol/times/vasco/rss2.xml";


    RSSHandler rh = new RSSHandler();
    List<Article> articles =  rh.getLatestArticles(feed);
    Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Number of articles " + articles.size());
    return fillData(articles);
}



private static List<JSONObject> fillData(List<Article> articles) {

    List<JSONObject> items = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
    for (Article article : articles) {
        JSONObject current = new JSONObject();
        try {
            buildJsonObject(article, current);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e("RSS ERROR", "Error creating JSON Object from RSS feed");
        }
        items.add(current);
    }

    return items;
}
 */
private static void buildJsonObject(Article article, JSONObject current) throws JSONException {
    String title = article.getTitle();
    String description = article.getDescription();
    String date = article.getPubDate();
    String imgLink = article.getImgLink();


    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    sb.append(BOLD_OPEN).append(title).append(BOLD_CLOSE);
    sb.append(BREAK);
    sb.append(description);
    sb.append(BREAK);
    sb.append(SMALL_OPEN).append(ITALIC_OPEN).append(date).append(ITALIC_CLOSE).append(SMALL_CLOSE);

    current.put("text", Html.fromHtml(sb.toString()));
    current.put("imageLink", imgLink);
}
```

}

Here is the rsshandler class;

```
public class RSSHandler extends DefaultHandler {

// Feed and Article objects to use for temporary storage
private Article currentArticle = new Article();
private List<Article> articleList = new ArrayList<Article>();

// Number of articles added so far
private int articlesAdded = 0;

// Number of articles to download
private static final int ARTICLES_LIMIT = 15;

//Current characters being accumulated
StringBuffer chars = new StringBuffer();


/* 
 * This method is called everytime a start element is found (an opening XML marker)
 * here we always reset the characters StringBuffer as we are only currently interested
 * in the the text values stored at leaf nodes
 * 
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler#startElement(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String, org.xml.sax.Attributes)
 */
public void startElement(String uri, String localName, String qName, Attributes atts) {
    chars = new StringBuffer();
}



/* 
 * This method is called everytime an end element is found (a closing XML marker)
 * here we check what element is being closed, if it is a relevant leaf node that we are
 * checking, such as Title, then we get the characters we have accumulated in the StringBuffer
 * and set the current Article's title to the value
 * 
 * If this is closing the "Item", it means it is the end of the article, so we add that to the list
 * and then reset our Article object for the next one on the stream
 * 
 * 
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler#endElement(java.lang.String, java.lang.String, java.lang.String)
 */
public void endElement(String uri, String localName, String qName) throws SAXException {

    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
    {
        Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article title: " + chars.toString());
        currentArticle.setTitle(chars.toString());

    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("description"))
    {
        Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article description: " + chars.toString());
        currentArticle.setDescription(chars.toString());
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate"))
    {
        Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article published date: " + chars.toString());
        currentArticle.setPubDate(chars.toString());
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("encoded"))
    {
        Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article content: " + chars.toString());
        currentArticle.setEncodedContent(chars.toString());
    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item"))
    {

    }
    else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
    {
        try {
            Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article link url: " + chars.toString());
            currentArticle.setUrl(new URL(chars.toString()));
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            Log.e("RSA Error", e.getMessage());
        }

    }




    // Check if looking for article, and if article is complete
    if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("item")) {

        articleList.add(currentArticle);

        currentArticle = new Article();

        // Lets check if we've hit our limit on number of articles
        articlesAdded++;
        if (articlesAdded >= ARTICLES_LIMIT)
        {
            throw new SAXException();
        }
    }
}





/* 
 * This method is called when characters are found in between XML markers, however, there is no
 * guarante that this will be called at the end of the node, or that it will be called only once
 * , so we just accumulate these and then deal with them in endElement() to be sure we have all the
 * text
 * 
 * (non-Javadoc)
 * @see org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler#characters(char[], int, int)
 */
public void characters(char ch[], int start, int length) {
    chars.append(new String(ch, start, length));
}





/**
 * This is the entry point to the parser and creates the feed to be parsed
 * 
 * @param feedUrl
 * @return
 */
public List<Article> getLatestArticles(String feedUrl) {
    URL url = null;
    try {

        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        url = new URL(feedUrl);

        xr.setContentHandler(this);
        xr.parse(new InputSource(url.openStream()));


    } catch (IOException e) {
        Log.e("RSS Handler IO", e.getMessage() + " >> " + e.toString());
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        Log.e("RSS Handler SAX", e.toString());
    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        Log.e("RSS Handler Parser Config", e.toString());
    }

    return articleList;
}
```

}

Here is the article class;

```
public class Article {

private long articleId;
private long feedId;
private String title;
private String description;
private String imgLink;
private String pubDate;
private URL  url;
private String encodedContent;
/**
 * @return the articleId
 */
public long getArticleId() {
    return articleId;
}
/**
 * @param articleId the articleId to set
 */
public void setArticleId(long articleId) {
    this.articleId = articleId;
}
/**
 * @return the feedId
 */
public long getFeedId() {
    return feedId;
}
/**
 * @param feedId the feedId to set
 */
public void setFeedId(long feedId) {
    this.feedId = feedId;
}
/**
 * @return the title
 */
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
/**
 * @param title the title to set
 */
public void setTitle(String title) {
    this.title = title;
}
/**
 * @return the url
 */
public URL getUrl() {
    return url;
}
/**
 * @param url the url to set
 */
public void setUrl(URL url) {
    this.url = url;
}
/**
 * @param description the description to set
 */
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;

    //parse description for any image or video links
    if (description.contains("<img ")){
        String img  = description.substring(description.indexOf("<img "));
        String cleanUp = img.substring(0, img.indexOf(">")+1);
        img = img.substring(img.indexOf("src=") + 5);
        int indexOf = img.indexOf("'");
        if (indexOf==-1){
            indexOf = img.indexOf("\"");
        }
        img = img.substring(0, indexOf);

        setImgLink(img);

        this.description = this.description.replace(cleanUp, "");
    }
}
/**
 * @return the description
 */
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
/**
 * @param pubDate the pubDate to set
 */
public void setPubDate(String pubDate) {
    this.pubDate = pubDate;
}
/**
 * @return the pubDate
 */
public String getPubDate() {
    return pubDate;
}
/**
 * @param encodedContent the encodedContent to set
 */


public void setEncodedContent(String encodedContent) {
    this.encodedContent = encodedContent;
}
/**
 * @return the encodedContent
 */
public String getEncodedContent() {
    return encodedContent;
}
/**
 * @param imgLink the imgLink to set
 */
public void setImgLink(String imgLink) {
    this.imgLink = imgLink;
}
/**
 * @return the imgLink
 */
public String getImgLink() {
    return imgLink;
}
```

}

Comment: The url is stored on the Article instance under "url" property, check the xml, the <link> element, has de article url

Comment: There is nothing in the xml, how can I grab the url from the code, do I use geturl, get item....ect

Comment: Ok I have added a Log.d in the RSSHandler class to capture the link and item log in the xml and used a toast to print the output but all I am getting is the rss link and the Image link not the article link.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Yeradis you were I simply added this to the code;

In the Handler class:

```
else if (localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
    {
        Log.d("LOGGING RSS XML", "Setting article link: " + chars.toString());
        currentArticle.setLink(chars.toString());
```

In the Article class:

```
private String link;
public String getLink() {
    return link;
}
/**
 * @param title the title to set
 */
public void setLink(String link) {
    this.link = link;
}
```

and in the Reader class

```
String link = article.getLink();
current.put("link", link);
```

Comment: I have managed to get the link into a toast but now I need to isolate the link information from the pub date description ect....